# Synchronizing SCPI communication over RS232

Tags: scpi

I have a power supply that has a reasonable implementation of SCPI over RS-232, but with the usual constraint that SRQ is unavailable, there is no STB side channel, and any bytes in the message buffer are immediately sent.

Now I'd like to be able to discern if a command is still operating, or if it simply does not give a response, and ideally do that without waiting for OPC (because long-running operations might not be finished yet, and I do not want to wait for them).

The best I could come up with so far is appending `;*STB?` to get the status byte at the end of execution, but that doesn't work if there is a syntax error in the command prior to that, that causes the entire line to be ignored.

Appending `*STB?` as a separate command is a little bit better, because it always generates a reply, but now the separator is a newline, which may also be part of a multi-line reply.

Is there a good generic strategy for discerning where command output ends, or do I need to introduce knowledge about individual commands?